# using regex to extract a portion of text from a file

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to use the following code:

```
x <- scan("myfile.txt", what="", sep="\n")

b <- grep('/^one/(.*?)/^four/', x, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

to extract a porting of text from myfile.txt

```
zero
one
two
three
four
five
```

the output I'm expecting is

```
one
two
three
four
```

I want to include the "one" and "four" I don't want to ditch them :)

But somehow the regex is not working, The console output is giving no error but no text either... ?

I am using print(b)

Comment: i have also tried print(b[1]) maybe i should iterate through the fector? but i thought the first line (the word "two") would be at b[2] it's not, there is nothing but "NA"

Comment: Look at the value of `x`: it is not one long string, it is a vector with one line in each item. `grep` tries to match against each item in the vector.

Comment: i tried to convert the vector to a string a <- paste(x, collapse = '')... still no luck

Comment: It might be helpful if you gave more info about what you're trying to do and why, as well as whether the words will always be "in order".  Why don't you want the result in a format that makes it easy to work with in R? Is there a reason to use R for this?  Are you trying to write a file, print to the screen, or assign a vector?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear on what you're looking for, but just for fun...

```
R> x
[1] "zero"  "one"   "two"   "three" "four"  "five" 

R> grep("one|four", x) # get the position of "one" and "four"
[1] 2 5
```

Subset `x` to only include the things between "one" and "four"

```
R> x[do.call(seq, as.list(grep("one|four", x)))]
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"
```

Comment: im looking to extract a block of text from a file and print tat block of text out to the console with new lines, not all on one line. also, can i use the ^ operator just like as in perl to say i want to match at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @ace007 If you read `?regex` carefully you'll see all the options available to you explained in great detail.

Comment: @ace007 you can take result here and pass it to `paste` with `collapse='\n'` to get the ouput you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub('one(.*)four','\\1',paste(x,collapse=''))
[1] "zerotwothreefive"
```

or to get space between words :

```
gsub('one(.*)four','\\1',paste(dat,collapse=' '))
[1] "zero  two three  five"
```

**Edit** after Gsee comment:

```
 gsub('.*(one.*four).*','\\1',paste(dat,collapse=' '))
[1] "one two three four"
```

But I think here no need to use regular expression :

```
 dat[seq(which(dat == 'one'),which(dat == 'four'))]
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"
```

of course you can use min if the previous index in which are not in the good order.

Comment: I think you're going for something like this: `gsub(".*(one.*four).*", "\\1", paste(x, collapse=" "))`.  Note the OP says `"I want to include the "one" and "four" I don't want to ditch them"`

Comment: @Gsee you re right...I am rerading the question.... yes you re right! I update my solution...but gsub looks ugly here!

Comment: I need them as new lines \n and how does this work?

   `b <- gsub('one(.*)four','\n',paste(dat, collapse=' '))`

Comment: @ace007, something like `cat(paste(x, collapse="\n"))`.  `cat` accepts a `file` argument also if that helps.